# WebClient.DownloadFile in application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have one problem with WebClient.DownloadFile

On asp.net server I have page with this code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Request.QueryString("Tool")) Then
    Dim Subor As String = Server.UrlDecode(Me.Request.QueryString("Tool"))
    Dim SuborCesta As String = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Downloads/Images/" & Subor & ".png")
    If IO.File.Exists(SuborCesta) Then
      Response.ClearHeaders()
      Response.ClearContent()
      Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
      Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ToolImage.png")
      Response.WriteFile(SuborCesta)
      Response.End()
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

By this code i download the pictures im desktop program, where I use:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ToolList.Count - 1
  Dim imageAddress As String = String.Empty
  Dim filename As String = String.Empty
  Try
    Dim fileReader As New WebClient()
    imageAddress = ToolList(i).ToolImage
    filename = ToolList(i).ToolFullName & ".png"
    If Not (System.IO.File.Exists(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Images\" + filename)) Then
      fileReader.DownloadFile(New Uri(imageAddress), My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Images\" + filename)
    End If
  Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
  End Try
Next
```

If I load page with query string in browser, image is downloaded. But if I use this in my program, image file on my disk is created, but the file contains html code from my .aspx page.

How to get and save the picture from request?

Comment: Did you include the required querystring in the request from your WebClient?

Comment: Yes, query string is included. This I control as first.

Answer (score 0):

try using the appropriate MIME type:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/png"
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. It looks like the image is downloaded but the method (WebClient.DownloadFile) only returns html page without picture.

Comment: Ok, i'll have to try reproduce the scenario myself tomorrow if you haven't already accepted an answer. Sleep tight!

Comment: Finnaly I found a solution. I create webservice, which send picture in bytes and client application use this code
    `Dim sluzba As New ServiceReference1.ApiSoapClient  If Not (System.IO.File.Exists(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Images\" + filename & ".png")) Then  Dim Img As Byte() = sluzba.GetImage(filename)  IO.File.WriteAllBytes(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Images\" + filename & ".png", Img)  End If`  This code works, but I don't know why the previous did not work.